# Forces On Toroidal Wind Tunnel wihen Wing is attached inside?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, aerodynamics, lift

Consider the attached Toroidal wind Tunnel.

[image]

The Wind tunnel is in Vacuum and the moving air and the attached wing are only inside the toroidal tunnel.

Will the mounted wing on the walls of the tunnel experience force
and move the Toroidal tunnel as shown in the picture.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Strongly disagree with the two close-voters who called this "an engineering question." I suspect they didn't actually read the question and saw something that visually looked like the type of model an engineer would make. This is a question about Newton's third law as applied to closed systems with internal forces. It might be a homework question though, so I won't answer it.